# Twitter Bootstrap 3 customized radio buttons crashed by fastclick.js

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fastclick.js

I use this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/wgw8zgzu/) witch works perfectly when i use it stand alone (without fastclick plugin):

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked> Option 1 (preselected)
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
    </label>
</div>
```

But when i use fastlick.js to improve click performance for mobile devices, when i press on the buttons the active class changes from one label to another, but the radio buttons are not being updated, it remains the same radio selected.

It took me some time to figure it out, i had to make the radio buttons visible using:

```
[data-toggle="buttons"] > .btn > input[type="radio"], [data-toggle="buttons"] > .btn > input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: block;
}
```

And after that i saw that the input radio remains still. You can open [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/wgw8zgzu/) with an ipad or an iphone to see the problem.

Is there any solution in order to make the radio buttons work and also keep the fastclick.js plugin in the same time?

Comment: The fiddle is not workable because `FastClick is not defined`.. But as far as I can see the bootstrap [javascript radio button](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons) uses jQuery to set value and add change handlers where fastclick does this the vanilla way.

Comment: I've updated the fastclick plugin on the example, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

...as fastclick suggests, add the 'needsclick' class to the wrapper btn-group...

```
<div class="btn-group needsclick" ...>
```